# AWS SDK for Python Sample Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, python

I'm trying to fetch metrics data from Cloud Watch using Python using the tutorial 'AWS SDK for Python Sample Project'.

I did the following

```
pip install boto3
```

Set up my credentials file

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
region = xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Here is the script

```
import boto3

# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# List metrics through the pagination interface
paginator = cloudwatch.get_paginator('list_metrics')
for response in paginator.paginate(Dimensions=[{'Name': 'LogGroupName'}],
                               MetricName='IncomingLogEvents',
                               Namespace='AWS/Logs'):
print(response['Metrics'])
```

When I run the program, I get the following:

```
[]
```

So, I'm assuming it authenticated w/o issues but since I have more than one instance, it doesn't know which instance metrics I desire?

If that is the case, where do I indicate the instanceid, or correct my assumption?

Comment: if you do a print of paginator what does it return?

Comment: @trozz `<botocore.client.CloudWatch.Paginator.ListMetrics object at 0x7f7293f2afd0>`